# Как использовать модули в Питон 3?

Tags: python, строки

Вот недавно решил скачать себе питон 3 (раньше стоял питон 2) и столкнулся с проблемой:
не могу использовать команду split из модуля string

```
import string
song = "The rain in Spain..."
string.split(song)
```

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
>     string.split(song)
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'split'`

Да и в принципе остальные команды я тоже не могу использовать! Вроде на питоне 2 у меня получалось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А там ее теперь [нет](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/string.html#module-string) в этом модуле. Теперь правильно писать так:

```
import string
song = "The rain in Spain..."
print(song.split())
```

И все работает как нужно.

Comment: спасибо!!! а есть ли нормальный перевод этой статьи что вы мне кинули?

Comment: Использовать методы класса string. Почему так - это нужно у дизайнеров языка спрашивать.